# Line stipple with OpenGL ES 2.0

Tags: shaders, opengl-es, opengl-es2

I found many threads about line stipple (dashed or dotted lines) with OpenGL ES2.0, but there are never any code examples or tutorials on how to implement it.

How do I implement line stipple in OpenGL ES 2.0?